# Installation of angular material in angular 5 in ubuntu 16.4.5 (ERROR : Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.)

Tags: angular, angular-material

Installation of angular material in angular 5 in ubuntu 16.4.5 :-

I've followed these steps: (https://v5.material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

- `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk`
- `npm install --save angular/material2-builds angular/cdk-builds`
- `npm install --save @angular/animations`

reference from link further steps

but this gives me the following errors:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(136,20): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(154,104): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(53,15): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(55,18): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
```

How could I resolve this error?

Comment: Yes, i got the same issue. I solved that in my previous project. But, my new project have the same error. I forgot how to solve it.

Comment: Still i try to figure it out. If i got the solution, I'll inform to you

Comment: I think it's some version mismatch problem. Try to install angular material version 5.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
npm install --save @angular/material@5.2.5 
npm install --save @angular/cdk@5.2.5
```